# Bash Shell doesn't recognize the letter "t"

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I have Cygwin running on a Windows 7 Box.  In what is a relatively new (and strange) development, the bash shell stopped recognizing the lowercase "t".  For example:

> I type `echo cat`, output is `ca`.
>   I type `more tmp.txt`, output is `mp.x does not exist` (or however it says the file isn't there).
>   I type `echo TTT`, output is `TTT`.

Anyone know about this one?

Comment: It only doesn't recognise the lowercase "t"? Not uppercase?

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with your terminal. Which one are you using (mintty, rxvt, cmd.exe, ...)? Do you see the same problem when you try a different one?

Comment: This should probably be closed as "too localized" but what a weird problem! Do you see the `t` you type or not?

Comment: I doesn't happen with the command prompt (cmd.exe) which is what I primarily use.  I currently have installed ConEmu, but the problem predates that.  With Cygwin, bash is run in the existing command prompt shell, not in it's own shell.  Putty ssh works fine, nodejs repl, cpan, mysql - any other software application that is run inside the existing shell.

Comment: I do see the 't' when I type it.  It is just not outputted.

Comment: Check your `~/.inputrc` to see if you have anything special for readline. Also, check `bind -p`

Comment: I'll be dammed.  That was it.  Using *clink* with *ConEmu*.  This was the offending line: `"\t":     clink-completion-shim`.  I assume that's for tab-completion.  Do you know why that line caused the error?  You should post your answer so I can vote for it.  That was a hell of a catch.

Comment: My guess is that "\" need so be double escaped like this "\\t"